# problem with appendices and toc

Tags: pdflatex

I have added to my document appendices like that

```
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Załączniki}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Załączniki}

\appendix
\clearpage
\addappheadtotoc
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Załączniki}
\appendixpage
\input{app1//app1.tex}
```

and it works with one exception. In table of contents it occurs twice:
[image]

How to remove the second one?

Comment: I wonder if this should be protected since the answer has been found and it can't be migrated to the tex stackexchange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. \appendixpage*